# sscanf replacing previous values

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, scanf

Thanks in advance for your help. I have an issue using the sscanf to scan a txt for some values, couldn't find something similar already posted here. This is what the txt I'm reading looks like:

```
1 NAME 211.505 42.63
2 NAME 335.475 42.63
3 NAME 449.645 42.63
4 NAME 512.435 42.63
```

And this is the part giving the problem:

```
double contacts[N-1][1];
i = 0;

while(fgets(cLine,100,inFile) != NULL) {
    sscanf(cLine,"%d %s %lf %lf",
        &cNum[i],
        cVarName[i],
        &contacts[i][0],
        &contacts[i][1]);
    i++;
}
```

It works fine at every step, but it seems that at i, the sscanf replaces the i-1 value.

It may be something stupid I couldn't notice, sorry if it is the case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How is `i` initialized?  What are the types of these variables? How do you prevent the code from indexing off the end of the arrays when the file has more lines?  Why isn't `cVarName` also indexed with `i`?

Comment: i initialized at 0, only the contacts arrays matter, I prevent that by setting the txt file myself and knowing exactly the number of lines (but I also added an if and break at one point, that is not the issue).

Comment: You know arrays in C and C++ are indexed from 0..n-1, not 1..n, right?  Line 1 will go into array[0].  If sscanf "replaces the i-1 value" and it's initialized to 0, are you saying that the first line is read into the -1 index??

Comment: I do, thanks for your answer. The point is that at step i, it loads the i values but ALSO changes the i-1 previously defined values.d. I deleted the fprintfs I used to save the arrays and that allowed me to deduce that.

Comment: Line 1 goes into array[0] and at the same time array[-1] gets 0. Line 2 goes into array[1] and at the same time, array[2][0] goes into array[1][1], etc.. (in this order, don't know why).

Comment: Can you show how the arrays are declared?  What header files are included?

Comment: double contacts[N-1][1];

and the headers are

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ldata.h"

Comment: I used to print the result I scanned at each iteration, so the output file showed exactly the correct results (all 200 of them). But when I printed the results after the whole loop was finished, it showed the problem and that it overwrites not only the values corresponding to the i iteration but the previous ones also (I checked for i - 1, but maybe it changes ALL previously scanned values).

Answer (score 0):

The `contacts` array should be declared:

```
double contacts[N][2];
```

since you are indexing it as `contacts[i][1]`; it must have at least 2 entries in the second dimension.  An array declaration specifies the number of entries you want in each dimension, not the index of the highest element.  I'm just guessing that you want `N` entries in the first dimension since it seems strange to declare `N-1`, but as I pointed out before, you have no bound on the loop, so it's hard to tell.

C does not perform array bounds checks, so by declaring the array as having only 1 element in the second dimension, you will find that:

```
&contacts[i][1] == &contacts[i+1][0]
```

So, for each iteration after the first, each time you store into `contacts[i][0]`, you will be overwriting `contacts[i-1][1]`.  The last iteration will store `contacts[i][1]` in `contacts[i+1][0]`.

Try printing the addresses of the elements to see what's going on.